# Square-Connect 422 error when trying to add items

Tags: square-connect

I am getting a 422 error while trying to add items to my square account using the API (POST).  Please let me know what is wrong.

Here is what I am sending
URL: https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/items

Header:

```
      Authorization: Bearer {Personal Token}
      Accept: application/json
      Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
    [{
       "visibility": "PRIVATE",
       "available_online": false,
       "available_for_pickup": false,
       "name": "New Item",
       "variations": [{
        "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
        "name": "Regular",
        "price_money": {
         "currency_code": "USD",
         "amount": 6000
        },
        "sku": "new_item"
       }]
      }]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Item` object being provided in the above example is inside an array, which is incorrect. If you delete the outermost square brackets from the above example, the request should succeed.